# Print text to image in colors with imagemagic

Tags: image, bash, shell, imagemagick

I want to print text on image but in different colors

So far I got this

```
 convert -pointsize 50 Picture3.jpg -background none label:'Some Text'  -flatten  layer_simple.jpg
```

and the result is image printed with "Some Text" on the left top corner.
The color is black

also I do not know hot to use the -gravity center,

Answer (score 0):

```
convert -fill blue -pointsize 50 Picture3.jpg -background none label:'Some Text'  -flatten  layer_simple.jpg
```

**-fill blue** , is the answer